# Implementation of Oauth2 with Java springboot app and angular on ui side

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

there is my application in which I am using Angular on the UI side and on the API side I have a spring boot app and for managing users- using the AWS Cognito user pool. currently, I am able to connect with my user pools in my application, which means I have manually implemented the verification, decoding, and filtering id tokens and access tokens based on role manually. but I want to use the spring oauth2 feature to do the same and want to remove manual verification and boilerplate code.

can anyone help me please to provide the steps how can I achieve it, if you know certain steps,
it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Didi you checked this link? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: yeah, thanks @GopalMishra, but initially following this I tried to migrate my code to Oauth2, but doesn't help me out

Comment: Could you post what you have done? What error you are getting? Some code snippets to reproduce the issue? P.S. I'm sorry for typos in the previous comment.